# Differences between 滑鼠 (huá shŭ) and 鼠标 (shŭ biāo)

Tags: translation

I've seen both 滑鼠 (huá shŭ) and 鼠标 (shŭ biāo) used as translations for "computer mouse". Are there differences in meaning, and which is more commonly used?

Comment: They both refer to the physical mouse device. Which translation to use depends on where you are using the term. In Mainland China 鼠标 is used whereas in Taiwan, Hong Kong, and other places 滑鼠 is more prefered. https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%BC%A0%E6%A0%87

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They both refer to the physical mouse device. Which translation to use depends on where you are using the term. In Mainland China 鼠标 is used whereas in Taiwan, Hong Kong, and other places 滑鼠 is more preferred.

Reference: [維基百科](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%BC%A0%E6%A0%87)

Comment: Do these terms also refer to the mouse cursor? Thanks.

Comment: "Mouse cursor" in Hong Kong and Taiwan usually is translated as 滑鼠游標. In Mainland China as 鼠標光標. I could imagine in Hong Kong/Taiwan 滑鼠游標 could be abbreviated as 鼠標 and people could understand.

Answer (score 1):

Only people in china will uses 鼠标, Taiwan and Hong Kong are common uses 滑鼠.